# Invalidating/Disabling Entity Framework cache

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, caching

I see there are plenties of question on EF cache, but I have found no solution yet to my problem.

### The straight question is

How do I completely disable Entity Framework 6 cache? Or, can I programmatically tell EF to forget about the cache because something happened to data?

#### Background

First, I have **inherited** an application made of a strange mixture of EF (model-first to define entities) and plain old SQL (to manipulate data). What I did was to refactor the application in order to:

- Make simple queries (like `GetAll()` for an entity) use EF6 LINQ
- Leave complex data manipulation in SQL, using `DbContext.Database.Connection` when needed
- Add `Spring.Web` support to enable DI and transactions (not yet)

At the current point, I have reorganized the code so that the main function of the application (running complex SQL queries on huge datasets) works as it did before, but then lookup domain entity manipulation is done smarter using *as most* Entity Framework as possible

#### As most....

One of the pages I inherited is a multi-checkbox page I'm going to show you for best understanding. I won't discuss the previous implementor's choice, because it's cheaper to fix my current problem and later refactor code than blocking development for a broken feature.

This is how the page looks like

[image]

Basically the `Controller` method is the following

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string[] codice, string[] flagpf, string[] flagpg, string[] flagammbce, string[] flagammdiv, string[] flagammest,
        string[] flagintab, string[] flagfinanz, string[] flagita, string[] flagest, string pNew){
            Sottogruppo2015Manager.ActivateFlagFor("pf", flagpf);
            Sottogruppo2015Manager.ActivateFlagFor("pg", flagpg);
            Sottogruppo2015Manager.ActivateFlagFor("ammbce", flagammbce);
            Sottogruppo2015Manager.ActivateFlagFor("ammdiv", flagammdiv);
            Sottogruppo2015Manager.ActivateFlagFor("ammest", flagammest);
            Sottogruppo2015Manager.ActivateFlagFor("intab", flagintab);
            Sottogruppo2015Manager.ActivateFlagFor("finanz", flagfinanz);
            Sottogruppo2015Manager.ActivateFlagFor("ita", flagita);
            Sottogruppo2015Manager.ActivateFlagFor("est", flagest);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { pNew });
 }
```

Each `string[]` parameter is a column in the table. The `ActivateFlagFor` method runs two queries in sequence

```
UPDATE table SET --param1-- = 0;
UPDATE table SET --param1-- = 1 where id in (--param2--)
```

#### When the cache kicks in

The following is the behaviour:

- I first load the page issuing a LINQ select: checks match the ones and zeroes in columns
- I change one or more checks and submit
- The controller issues the queries to update checks in the DB
- Before **redirecting** (!means new request!) to reload the page, I check the DB and the changes are applied
- The page reloads issuing the same LINQ select above: **old checks are displayed**

I am sure that this is a caching problem, because reloading the application fixes the problem.
Since the main feature of the application is totally SQL based, changes to lookup tables are reflected into main operation and that's the correct behaviour.

I understand that EF caching is a great feature for performance, but in my case I just don't want it, at least until I migrate the whole application to LINQ DML (probably impossible).

#### How I use the `DbContext`

Of course some of you may ask "how do you use your DbContext?" "do you dispose of it correctly?".

- I haven't yet integrated Spring transactions in my Manager classes
- Each object that performs *actions* on the database is a `I<Entity>Manager` extending `BaseManager`
- `DbContext` is a request-scoped Spring object. I already [asked about disposing request-scoped objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28232703/disposable-request-scoped-object) but I currently implemented a workaround that, while bad, **correctly disposes of** the DbContext at the end of the request.

#### Example code

```
public class ExampleManagerImpl : BaseManager, IExampleManager
{
    public void ActivateFlagFor(string aFlag, string[] aList)
    {
        string sql = "UPDATE table SET flag" + aFlag + " = 0";
        RunStatementV1(sql);

        if (aList != null && aList.Any())
        {
            sql = "UPDATE table SET flag" + aFlag + " = 1 WHERE id in (" + aList.ToCsvApex() + ")";
            RunStatementV1(sql);
        }
    }

    public IList<Models.Example> GetAll()
    {
        return DataContext.example.ToList(); //I don't dispose of the DataContext willingly
    }
}
```

and

```
public abstract class BaseManager {

    public DbContext DataContext { get; set; } //Autowired

    protected void RunStatementV1(string aSqlStatement)
    {
        IDbConnection connection = DataContext.Database.Connection;
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed || connection.State == ConnectionState.Broken) connection.Open(); //Needed because sometimes I found the connection closed, even if I don't dispose of it
        using (IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = aSqlStatement;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

    }
}
```

#### What I tried

- [How to stop entity framework caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346494/how-to-stop-entity-framework-caching) : disabling lazy loading didn't work
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22818783/471213: `Detach` seems to solve the problem but I'd need to apply it to dozen of entities, in order to revert someday in the future

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If you want to completely ignore EF6's cache for data retrieval, then add `AsNoTracking()` to the end of your query (before calling `ToList()` or doing anything else that would execute the query.

[MSDN on `AsNoTracking()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn237200%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

Please note that doing so will neither check the cache for existing data, nor will it add the results of the database call to the cache.  Additionally, Entity Framework will not automatically detect changes to entities that you retrieve from the database.  If you do want to change any entities and save them back to the database, you'll need to attach the changed entities before calling `SaveChanges()`.

Your method is currently:

```
public IList<Models.Example> GetAll()
{
    return DataContext.example.ToList();
}
```

It would change to:

```
public IList<Models.Example> GetAll()
{
    return DataContext.example.AsNoTracking().ToList();
}
```

If you are interested in other options for dealing with EF's cache, I've written a [blog post about EF6 Cache Busting](http://codethug.com/2016/02/19/Entity-Framework-Cache-Busting/).

Comment: AsNoTracking is not always good, i had a long term consist of tries and search due to using that, because, for example, the record couldn't get deleted

Comment: let me add any kind of attaching did not worked for me... which you refer to in here
http://codethug.com/2016/02/19/Entity-Framework-Cache-Busting/

Comment: @deadManN if you open a new question and link to it here, I'll be glad to help look into it.  But without any details it's hard to know how to resolve your problem.

Comment: i change my ways in that problem, and solved it... just passed by and thought i should say it

Answer (score 9):

I had this trouble too, but I could fix it.

I'm using Repository Pattern and using default DI of .Net Core.
I've been using AddSingleton(...), but it's wrong to use with DbContext.

So, I've changed to AddScoped, like I read from docs: **Scoped lifetime services are created once per request.**

It has solved my problem.

[You must read this section from ms docs: Service Lifetimes and Registration Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes-and-registration-options)

Comment: This helped me so much!